Second Button for Opening Modal Not Responding on First Click and It Not Closing Properly
I’m working on a project where users need to sign a form using a signature pad. The form requires three separate signatures, and I have implemented three buttons to open modals for the signature pad. However, I am encountering an issue with the second button:
When I click the second button to open its modal, it does not open on the first click. It only opens after clicking it a second time.
Once the modal opens, it does not close properly.
This issue only happens with the second button, regardless of the order in which the buttons are clicked. The first and third buttons work perfectly fine for both opening and closing their respective modals.
I suspect there might be an issue in my code related to event handling or modal initialization, but I’m not sure what’s causing this inconsistency.
here is the snippet of my code for the buttons:
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="candidate_sign">Tandatangan</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signatureModal" data-user="candidate">Add Signature</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="candidate_signature" id="candidate_signature" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['candidate_signature'] ?? '') ?>">
        <div id="candidate-signature-container" class="signature-container">
            <!-- The signature that been saved will be placed here -->
            <?php if (!empty($form_data['candidate_signature'])): ?>
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['candidate_signature']); ?>" alt="Candidate Signature" class="signature-img">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="hr_sign">Tandatangan</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signatureModal" data-user="hr">Add Signature</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="hr_signature" id="hr_signature" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['hr_signature'] ?? '') ?>">
        <div id="hr-signature-container" class="signature-container">
            <!-- HR signature will be displayed here -->
            <?php if (!empty($form_data['hr_signature'])): ?>
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['hr_signature']); ?>" alt="HR Signature" class="signature-img">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="comben_sign">Tandatangan</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signatureModal" data-user="comben">Add Signature</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="comben_signature" id="comben_signature" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['comben_signature'] ?? '') ?>">
        <div id="comben-signature-container" class="signature-container">
            <!-- Comben signature will be displayed here -->
            <?php if (!empty($form_data['comben_signature'])): ?>
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['comben_signature']); ?>" alt="Comben Signature" class="signature-img">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

this snippet is for the modals:
<div class="modal" id="signatureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signature" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 100%; max-width:100%;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"  style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Electronic Signature</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right; margin-top: -5px;">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Tab navigation -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="signatureTab">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#add-signature" data-toggle="tab">Add Signature</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
                <!-- Tab contents -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="signatureTabContent">
                    <!-- Add Signature Tab -->
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="add-signature">
                        <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad border bg-white" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
                        <p class="text-muted small">*Your signature will be saved in the database.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="undo">Undo</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear">Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="done">Done</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

and here is the snippet for the functions:
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
    const clearButton = document.querySelector('#clear');
    const undoButton = document.querySelector('#undo');
    const doneButton = document.querySelector('#done');
    let currentUserType = ''; // To track the current user type (candidate, hr, or comben)

    // jQuery-specific logic
    $j(() => {
        // Initialize tabs
        $j('.nav-tabs a').tab();

        // Track which button triggered the modal
        $j('button[data-target="#signatureModal"]').on("click", function () {
            currentUserType = $j(this).data("user"); // Set current user type
            updateSignatureButtonText(currentUserType); // Update button text for the specific user
            $j('#signatureTab a[href="#add-signature"]').tab('show'); // Show the add signature tab
        });

        // Resize canvas when modal is shown
        $j("#signatureModal").on("shown.bs.modal", resizeCanvas);
        $j(window).on("resize", resizeCanvas);
    });

    const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
        backgroundColor: null,
        penColor: 'black',
        lineWidth: 10
    });

    function resizeCanvas() {
        const ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
        canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
        signaturePad.clear();
    }

    function closeModal() {
        $j('#signatureModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            $j("#signatureModal").modal("hide");
        });
    }

    clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => signaturePad.clear());

    undoButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const data = signaturePad.toData();
        if (data.length > 0) {
            data.pop();
            signaturePad.fromData(data);
        }
    });

    doneButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
            alert("Please provide a signature first.");
            return;
        }

        const dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/svg+xml");
        displayRecentSignature(dataURL, currentUserType);
        closeModal();
    });

    // Function to display the signature
    function displayRecentSignature(dataURL, userType) {
        const containerId = `${userType}-signature-container`; // Dynamically determine the container
        const recentSignatureContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);

        if (!recentSignatureContainer) {
            console.error(`Signature container for ${userType} not found`);
            return; // Exit if the container doesn't exist
        }

        // Clear previous signature in the specific container
        recentSignatureContainer.innerHTML = "";

        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = dataURL;
        img.alt = "Recent Signature";
        img.classList.add("recent-signature");
        img.style.width = "150px";
        img.style.height = "auto";

        recentSignatureContainer.appendChild(img);

        const hiddenInput = document.getElementById(`${userType}_signature`);
        hiddenInput.value = dataURL;

        // Update button text to "Edit Signature" after signature is added
        updateSignatureButtonText(userType);
    }

    // Function to update the signature button text
    function updateSignatureButtonText(userType) {
        const button = document.querySelector(`button[data-user="${userType}"]`);

        if (!button) {
            console.error(`Button for ${userType} not found`);
            return; // Exit if the button doesn't exist
        }

        const signatureField = document.getElementById(`${userType}_signature`).value;

        // Check if the signature field has a value and update the button text accordingly
        if (signatureField && signatureField.trim() !== "") {
            button.textContent = "Edit Signature"; // Change button text if signature exists
        } else {
            button.textContent = "Add Signature"; // Default button text if no signature
        }
    }

    // Call the function on page load to set the initial button text
    ["candidate", "hr", "comben"].forEach(userType => {
        updateSignatureButtonText(userType);
    });
});


I tried the following approaches to solve the issue:

Using .on('click') and .off('click') to handle the button clicks and modal events.
Adding console.log statements to debug the issue. The logs show that the button is being clicked, the modal opens, and it closes as expected. However, in practice, the modal does not open on the first click of the second button and does not close properly.
I tried adding a timeout to force the modal to hide after some time, but this did not resolve the issue either.

What I Expected:

The modal should open immediately when any button is clicked.
The modal should close properly when the close button is clicked.

What Actually Happened:

The second button requires two clicks to open its modal the first time.
Once opened, the modal for the second button does not close as expected.


In your code here, you add a new event listener on the shown.bs.modal event.
function closeModal() {
    $j('#signatureModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $j("#signatureModal").modal("hide");
    });
}

Which I think then listens for the modal to show (the second click) and then immediately closes it again. Maybe changing it to just
function closeModal() {
    $j("#signatureModal").modal("hide");
}



var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
    const clearButton = document.querySelector('#clear');
    const undoButton = document.querySelector('#undo');
    const doneButton = document.querySelector('#done');
    let currentUserType = ''; // To track the current user type (candidate, hr, or comben)

    // jQuery-specific logic
    $j(() => {
        // Initialize tabs
        $j('.nav-tabs a').tab();

        // Track which button triggered the modal
        $j('button[data-target="#signatureModal"]').on("click", function () {
            currentUserType = $j(this).data("user"); // Set current user type
            updateSignatureButtonText(currentUserType); // Update button text for the specific user
            $j('#signatureTab a[href="#add-signature"]').tab('show'); // Show the add signature tab
        });

        // Resize canvas when modal is shown
        $j("#signatureModal").on("shown.bs.modal", resizeCanvas);
        $j(window).on("resize", resizeCanvas);
    });

    const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
        backgroundColor: null,
        penColor: 'black',
        lineWidth: 10
    });

    function resizeCanvas() {
        const ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
        canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
        signaturePad.clear();
    }

    function closeModal() {
        $j("#signatureModal").modal("hide");
    }

    clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => signaturePad.clear());

    undoButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const data = signaturePad.toData();
        if (data.length > 0) {
            data.pop();
            signaturePad.fromData(data);
        }
    });

    doneButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
            alert("Please provide a signature first.");
            return;
        }

        const dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/svg+xml");
        displayRecentSignature(dataURL, currentUserType);
        closeModal();
    });

    // Function to display the signature
    function displayRecentSignature(dataURL, userType) {
        const containerId = `${userType}-signature-container`; // Dynamically determine the container
        const recentSignatureContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);

        if (!recentSignatureContainer) {
            console.error(`Signature container for ${userType} not found`);
            return; // Exit if the container doesn't exist
        }

        // Clear previous signature in the specific container
        recentSignatureContainer.innerHTML = "";

        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = dataURL;
        img.alt = "Recent Signature";
        img.classList.add("recent-signature");
        img.style.width = "150px";
        img.style.height = "auto";

        recentSignatureContainer.appendChild(img);

        const hiddenInput = document.getElementById(`${userType}_signature`);
        hiddenInput.value = dataURL;

        // Update button text to "Edit Signature" after signature is added
        updateSignatureButtonText(userType);
    }

    // Function to update the signature button text
    function updateSignatureButtonText(userType) {
        const button = document.querySelector(`button[data-user="${userType}"]`);

        if (!button) {
            console.error(`Button for ${userType} not found`);
            return; // Exit if the button doesn't exist
        }

        const signatureField = document.getElementById(`${userType}_signature`).value;

        // Check if the signature field has a value and update the button text accordingly
        if (signatureField && signatureField.trim() !== "") {
            button.textContent = "Edit Signature"; // Change button text if signature exists
        } else {
            button.textContent = "Add Signature"; // Default button text if no signature
        }
    }

    // Call the function on page load to set the initial button text
    ["candidate", "hr", "comben"].forEach(userType => {
        updateSignatureButtonText(userType);
    });
});
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@4.1.7/dist/signature_pad.umd.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="candidate_sign">Tandatangan</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signatureModal" data-user="candidate">Add Signature</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="candidate_signature" id="candidate_signature" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['candidate_signature'] ?? '') ?>">
        <div id="candidate-signature-container" class="signature-container">
            <!-- The signature that been saved will be placed here -->
            <?php if (!empty($form_data['candidate_signature'])): ?>
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['candidate_signature']); ?>" alt="Candidate Signature" class="signature-img">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="hr_sign">Tandatangan</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signatureModal" data-user="hr">Add Signature</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="hr_signature" id="hr_signature" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['hr_signature'] ?? '') ?>">
        <div id="hr-signature-container" class="signature-container">
            <!-- HR signature will be displayed here -->
            <?php if (!empty($form_data['hr_signature'])): ?>
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['hr_signature']); ?>" alt="HR Signature" class="signature-img">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="comben_sign">Tandatangan</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signatureModal" data-user="comben">Add Signature</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="comben_signature" id="comben_signature" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['comben_signature'] ?? '') ?>">
        <div id="comben-signature-container" class="signature-container">
            <!-- Comben signature will be displayed here -->
            <?php if (!empty($form_data['comben_signature'])): ?>
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($form_data['comben_signature']); ?>" alt="Comben Signature" class="signature-img">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<div class="modal" id="signatureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signature" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 100%; max-width:100%;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"  style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Electronic Signature</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right; margin-top: -5px;">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Tab navigation -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="signatureTab">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#add-signature" data-toggle="tab">Add Signature</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
                <!-- Tab contents -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="signatureTabContent">
                    <!-- Add Signature Tab -->
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="add-signature">
                        <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad border bg-white" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
                        <p class="text-muted small">*Your signature will be saved in the database.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="undo">Undo</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear">Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="done">Done</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 




Unfortunately, the issue persists. I also tried adding
$j('#signatureModal').modal('hide');
directly to the function for the Done button, but the problem remains unresolved.

Hmm.. I've added a StackSnippet to my answer and "it works for me". Maybe there is something else going on that isn't included in your code?

don't really have a clue, i already include all the necessary code for the modals
